# Save HTML5 Canvas Drawing App as a SVG file

Tags: javascript, html, svg, canvas

I'm doing a **canvas drawing app and I want to be able to export the image as an SVG file**. I already did the function to save the image as a png file but I have some troubles with the SVG part. Can you please help me?
This is the HTML code for the save png image button:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="toolbar">
        <a href="#" id="save" onclick="SaveImage()">
        <img src="save.png"></a>
    </div>

<canvas id="my-canvas" width="800" height="500"></canvas>

<div id="toolbar2">
    <a id="img-file" download="image.png">
    <button onClick="download()" type="button" class="button">Save as PNG</button></a>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
function SaveImage(){
    var imageFile = document.getElementById("img-file");
    imageFile.setAttribute('download', 'image.png');
    imageFile.setAttribute('href', canvas.toDataURL());
}
```

Please help. I`m not allowed to use other js libraries.

Comment: What have you tried to do? What issues did you face?

Comment: You want to convert the raster image of your canvas to a vector image and download it? And that without a library?

Comment: @OskarGrosser yes..it`s not possible without a library?

Comment: You _can_ re-implement what another library does already, it might just be one hell of a task. Maybe you can use some API of another site together with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or you could try implementing that conversion yourself. I don't think there is a standard way of doing this. (Don't take my word for it though.) Do you really need this, or is it optional?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert the bitmap image of the canvas directly to SVG (except if the bitmap image like the PNG that you have tried to export is the source of a `<image>` element in your SVG -- but I guess that that is not the idea).

Now that this is a drawing tool, you probably maintain the state of the editor with objects and/or another data structure. With that assumption, the entire image is already represented in a structured manner. And this structure could be used for generating an SVG image. Example: a circle is drawn on the canvas with a color, size and position: `{type: "circle", color: "red", x: 30, y: 56, r: 5}`. This object is drawn as an arc on the canvas, but at the same time it can also be turned into a SVG `<circle>` element.

There are probably more libraries that can handle this for you. fabricjs could be an example. Here I link to the `toSVG()` function: [JSDoc: Class: Canvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toSVG).